# Why div have different animation in these two cases

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two divs with animation, both are doing the same but with different animation. I have

```
$(document).ready( function(){
  $('#show_hide_button').click( function() {
    $('#some_box').animate({ width: 'toggle' });
  });
});
```

Whole code in in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xLHb8/192/

Can anyone please explain to me why first div is animating right to left, left to right and second div is animating always to top left corner.

How can I make second div animate same as first div?

Comment: You haven't assigned the `.second` width properly in the css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the relevant details in your code should be included in your question (in addition to providing the fiddle). But so you have the following CSS:

```
#some_box {
  background: #fc0;
  width: 25%;
  height: 200px;
}

.second img {  
  max-width:100%;
  max-height:100%;
}

.second {   
  width: 200px;
}
```

With the following HTML:

```
<button id="show_hide_button">click me</button>
<div id="some_box"></div>

<div class="second">   
    <img src="http://piq.codeus.net/static/media/userpics/piq_66223.png" />; 
</div>
```

Note that you're setting the `img` to have a maximum width and height of its parent container. So because you're toggling the width of the *parent*, as parent collapses, the image is scaling down. Further, since you don't have a height setting on the `img`, its height is going to animate along with the animated width. This creates the effect of the image animating to the top left corner.

Without further details, it's hard to say how to fix your code to achieve the desired effect.

**Update**

If you want the width *only* to collapse, you can set a pixel height on your image so that it doesn't scale in proportion to its width:

```
.second img {  
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}
```

You can also put both animations in a single click event handler, like so:

```
$(document).ready( function(){
  $('#show_hide_button').click( function() {
    $('#some_box').animate({ width: 'toggle'});
    $('.second').animate({ width: 'toggle' });
  });
});
```

Forked your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/u1sdd8j5/1/

**Update 2**

From the comments, it seems like you want the image to collapse to the left, without losing the aspect ratio. We need to get a little creative to pull that off, especially if you're looking for a solution involving `jQuery.animate()`. The image actually needs to move downwards as it is scaled down. We can pull that off by animating the `<img>` itself, rather than its container, and adjusting its top margin at the same time animate its width.

Revised CSS (making the containers the same size for consistency):

```
#some_box {
  background: #fc0;
  width: 25%;
  height: 200px;
}

.second {
  width: 25%;
  height: 200px;
}

.second img {  
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

Revised JS:

```
$(document).ready( function(){
  $('#show_hide_button').click( function() {
    $('#some_box').animate({ width: 'toggle' });

    var $secondImg = $('.second img'),
        secondImgMargin = $secondImg.is(':visible') ? '50%' : 0;

    $('.second img').animate({
      width: 'toggle',
      marginTop: secondImgMargin
    });
  });
});
```

Note that we need to first determine whether or not the `<img>` is visible. If it is, then we want to animate the top margin to 50%. If it's not, then switch the top margin back to 0.

Here's a new forked fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xwanm9ze/1/

**Final Note**

All of this might be easier to achieve with CSS3 transitions. You would want to set up a class that toggles the animation. And you can specify the [transform-origin](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform-origin.asp) which, in this case, would be 'left center'.

Comment: sorry i am kinda new to this site, but thank you.
Is there any way to make responsible image have same animation like my first div?

Comment: What do you mean by "same animation"? Are you trying to have the width collapse while the height of the image stays the same?

Comment: @1110001110010001 replace your second selector with this one and problem solved $('.second img').animate({ width: 'toggle' });

Comment: @eugensunic That will not work, as the image's height will still collapse as its width is animated.

Comment: @ eugen sunic i try it did same thing for me :/
@ benjarwar yes, exactly that, just like it does in first yellow div, but only diff is that i want my img stay responsive (does not matter if it is img like in this case or background-image of div) is that possible?

Comment: So what you're saying is you want the image to maintain its aspect ratio as the width is scaled down. But you also want the image to appear to only collapse horizontally?

Comment: Possible, not necessarily simple. See **Update 2** above.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that you added a relative width and height attribute to the  inside the second div and did not give a height and width attribute to the second div. This way, the image controls the height and width of the second div, since it has no height and width attribute.

- In your case, a solution would be to give the second div a fixed width and height
- Also, for the JQuery, you only need one $(document).ready function

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#show_hide_button').click(function () {
        $('#some_box').animate({
            width: 'toggle'
        });
        $('.second').animate({
            width: 'toggle'
        });
    });
});
```

```css
#some_box {
    background: #fc0;
    width: 25%;
    height: 200px;
}
.second img {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
.second {
    width:200px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="show_hide_button">click me</button>
<div id="some_box"></div>
<div class="second">
    <img src="http://piq.codeus.net/static/media/userpics/piq_66223.png" />
</div>
```

Comment: Ah ok thank you, I know that with fixed width and height, i was wondering is there any way to do this with responsible div or image?

    $(".second").stop(true, false).show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 2000);

I did this but it slides whole div, from defined side, but not that i rly want that :/

Comment: If you mean, that you want to have the same animation for your divs, you can add multiple selectors to your animation: $(".second, #some_box").stop(true, false).show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 2000);